# Implement an interface with a method signature whose generic parameters extend an interface

Tags: java, generics

Below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to create `LibraryRunner` which implements `GenericRunner`. However I'm getting an IDE warning that `LibraryRunner` does not implement the methods in the `GenericRunner` interface. Which makes sense, the method signature doesn't match, but how can I make the method signature match while still using the `LibraryCalculator` which extends the `GenericCalculator`?

```
public class LibraryRunner implements GenericRunner {
    @Override
    public <T> T run(LibraryCalculator<T> calculator) {
        return T;
    }
}

public interface GenericRunner {
    <T, A> T run(GenericCalculator<T, A> calculator);
}


public interface LibraryCalculator<T> extends GenericCalculator<T, LibraryAlgorithm> {
    T calc(LibraryAlgorithm algorithm) throws LibraryException;
}

public interface GenericCalculator<T, A> {
    T calc(A algorithm) throws Exception;
}


public class LibraryException extends Exception {
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the interfaces are defined, you cannot override the method and change its signature, even if `LibraryCalculator` is a subtype of `GenericCalculator`. The other answer explains why.

One way to solve that is to parameterize the `GenericRunner` interface with the calculator type:

```
public interface GenericRunner<T, A, C extends GenericCalculator<T, A>> {
    T run(C calculator);
}

public class LibraryRunner<T> implements GenericRunner<T, LibraryAlgorithm, LibraryCalculator<T>> {

    @Override
    public T run(LibraryCalculator<T> calculator) {
        ...
    }

}
```

But note that you cannot return an `Object` in the `LibraryRunner` method, as it does not match `T`. If you want to return a specific type like `Object` (which defeats the purpose of the generic `LibraryCalculator`), you have to specify it explicitly:

```
public class LibraryRunner implements GenericRunner<Object, LibraryAlgorithm, LibraryCalculator<Object>> {

    @Override
    public Object run(LibraryCalculator<Object> calculator) {
        return new Object();
    }

}
```

If that's not what you want, then it's up to the user of `LibraryRunner` to decide which type `T` should be bound to.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, tyvm! And yea you're right about the `Object`. I just kind of threw that in there when writing the question, but I do return a generic `T` object in my code.

Answer (score 2):

When you override a method or implement it, you always need to satisfy the condition of the overridden method, for example you should still be able to call LibraryRunner.run with a parameter GenericCalculator. else it wont make sense to write:

```
LibraryRunner libRunner = new LibraryRunner();
GenericRunner genRunner = libRunner;
genRunner.run(new GenericCalculator<>());
```

Overriding the exception does work because when you call `GenericCalculator.calc` you are expecting any exception and calling `LibraryCalculator.calc` narrow it down to only `LibraryException`.

you can look on overriding methods as promise more information.

Comment: Was looking for a way to accomplish the goal in the original question, but I appreciate the explanation about what I was doing wrong and why the `LibraryException` worked.